# What languages have properties which can have assigned getters and setters?

Tags: programming-languages, properties

Java doesn't. (It's just convention)

Delphi does. 
I believe C# does.

What other languages do?

**Edit:**
I should have given an example:

Delphi: (beware, it's been a while, I may get this wrong)

```
 type
   TSomething = class
   fEmployeeNum: String;
    property employeeNum: String read fEmployeeNum write setEmployeeNum;
   end;

 procedure TSomething.setEmployeeNum(var val: String);
 begin
   fEmployeeNum := val;
 end;
```

Comment: I think this should be a community wiki question, since there's no "answer" that would be "best".

Comment: C# does support conventional getters and setters, and it also has a short form for the lazy coder :)  I.E.: public string myString { get; set; }

Comment: @S. Lott Good point! I forget about that from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does.

```
class SomeClass( object ):
def f_get( self ):
    return self.value
fprop = property( f_get )
```

Code for setter is similar.

Comment: Actually, this was the inspiration for the question.

Answer (score 3):

C# does (just to provide an example):

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; private set; }
    public string Bargain
    {
        get { return this._Bargain; }
        set { this._Bargain = value; }
    }
    private string _Bargain;
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving examples of both the conventional way and Auto Properties.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby does through `attr_reader`, `attr_writer`, and `attr_accessor` (for read/write):

```
class SomeClass
  attr_reader :foo #read-only
  attr_writer :bar #write-only
  attr_accessor :baz #read and write

  ...
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: class X ; attr_reader :foo, def initialize(foo) ; @foo = foo ; end ; end ; X.new('ape').foo #=> 'ape'

Comment: Thanks rampion, but I was hoping for a nicely formatted one like the others here.  By all means post it as your own answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: This whole thing ought to be CW anyway, but I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET does through the Property keyword.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't under the standard, but you can create the capacity through templates.

Answer (score 0):

[objective c](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-properties-setters-and-dot-syntax.html) and you can be lazy with the synthesize keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl 6,

```
use v6;

sub foo() is rw {
    state $foo;
    return new Proxy:
        FETCH => method { return $foo },
        STORE => method($to) { $foo = $to };
}

foo = "Hello, world!";
say foo;
```

...at least in theory.  Doesn't seem to work with Rakudo r38250.